# Is simple extension $\mathbb{Q}(\cos\pi/9):\mathbb{Q}$ algebraic and normal?

Tags: galois-theory

I am trying to prove this question:

Q: show that the simple extension $\mathbb{Q}(\cos\pi/9):\mathbb{Q}$   is an algebraic extension and also normal extension?

Thank you

Comment: Hint: show that $\cos\pi/9,\cos2\pi/9$ and $\cos4\pi/9$ are a full set of conjugates.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\cos\pi/9)$ is a subfield of the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/18})$.

Comment: thank you guys but still not clear how to prove it?

Comment: @Koam Ali: note that $\cos3x=4\cos^3 x-3\cos x.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\Bbb Q(\cos\pi/9) = \Bbb Q\left(\frac12(\zeta_{18} + \zeta_{18}^{-1})\right) \subseteq \Bbb Q(\zeta_{18})$$

The latter is an abelian algebraic extension of $\Bbb Q$, and therefore the required extension is algebraic and normal.